# Backbone models not always setting the correct data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a backbone model that is mix of single attributes, other models and collections.

To create this model and collection within a parent model scenario my model code looks like this,

```
App.Models.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({

urlRoot: "http://" + App.API_ROOT + "/project",

defaults: {
    visible: true
},

initialize: function() {

    var clients = this.get('clients');
    var pm = this.get('projectmanager');
    this.set('project_manager', new App.Models.User(pm));

    var sp = this.get('salesperson');
    this.set('sales_person', new App.Models.User(sp));

    this.set('clients', new App.Models.Client(clients));

    this.set('status_text', this.getStatusText(this.get('status')));

},

getStatusText: function(status) {
    switch(status) {
        case "0":
            return 'Archived';
        break;
        case "1":
            return 'Pending';
        break;
        case "2":
            return 'Active';
        break;
        case "3":
            return 'Complete';
        break;
    }
}
```

});

However occassional a model will be returned where the client attribute has not been set to a model, but has remained as an object, why would this be? Is there a better way to achieve my goal? Of models and collections within a parent model?

Comment: can you add some sample code of how you are instantiating the model, and how you are checking the client attribute?

Comment: How do you set the `App.API_ROOT` value?